# Cannot lowercase the QueryString

Tags: javascript

I am trying to lowercase a query string and get the value even if the URL is with capital letters.

**This is works - I can get the value:**

```
 ?serialid=1234
```

**This does not work - I Cannot get the value (Capital S):**

```
 ?Serialid=1234
```

I would like to match both cases.

**My script:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     var a = getQueryString("serialid");
     $('#SerialIdHP').val(a);
 });

 function getQueryString(key) {

     var vars = [],
         hash;
     var hashes = (window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&')).toString().toLowerCase();

     for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
         hash = hashes[i].split('=');
         vars.push(hash[0]);
         vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
     }
     return vars[key];
 }
```

Comment: You can push `lowercase` in `vars = []`, like `hash[0].toLowerCase()` and also use "getQueryString("serialid").toLowerCase()"

Comment: I would use the toLowerCase() function before slicing/splitting the string.

Comment: Is there any good reason you need to read these parameters case-insensitive? If you're trying to deal with query string you should know the precise names of these parameters (including their cases). What you're trying to achieve here is laziness.

Answer (score 3):

Use `toLowerCase()` to convert key

```
function getQueryString(url, key) {
    var vars = [],
        hash;
    var hashes = (url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&'));

    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0].toLowerCase());
        vars[hash[0].toLowerCase()] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars[key.toLowerCase()];
}

var url = "http://something.com?serialid=1234 "
var a = getQueryString(url, "SerialId");
alert(a);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T9BsR/1/

Comment: What is the reason of creating an array of parameters if only one of them is returned?

Comment: I think its better to lower-case the return of this function, that way this function can also be used when you don't want to lower case a querystring

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a = getQueryString("serialid").toLowerCase();
    $('#SerialIdHP').val(a);
});

function getQueryString(key) {

    var vars = [],
        hash;
    var hashes = (window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&')).toString().toLowerCase();

    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars[key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler function that does most of the heavy lifting. It retrieves the query vars in an object:

```
function parseQuery(query) {

  var queryvars = {}
    , patt = /[?&]([^&]+)=([^&]+)/g;

  decodeURIComponent(query).replace(patt, function(_, key, val){
    queryvars[key.toLowerCase()] = val;
  });

  return queryvars;
}

var queryvars - parseQuery('?Serialid=1234');
//^ {
//    serialid: "1234"
//  }
```

`queryvars` will contain all the variables from the url in lowercase in key:value pairs. To access the variable and make sure it's always lowercase, you can crate another helper:

```
function getQueryVar(key, query) {
  return parseQuery(query)[key.toLowerCase()];
}

var serialid = getQueryVar('SerialID', window.location.search);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'm against the method you're trying to achieve here, because you should know precisely the names of query parameters (including cases).

Anyway, the answer you're looking for is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a = getQueryString("serialid");
    $('#SerialIdHP').val(a);
});

function getQueryString(parameter) {
    var regex = new RegExp(parameter + "=([^&$]*)","i");
    var match = window.location.search.match(regex);
    return match ? match[1] : '';
}
```